# how to list spreadsheets only from a folder or to cast a file object into a spreadsheet object

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I would like to fill a sheet from values I get from a sheet of other spreadsheets in the same folder.

How can I call `getSheetByName()` from the files I list in the folder?

My code:

```
function listFilesInFolder() {

    var spsh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var spshid = spsh.getId();
    var folder = DriveApp.getFileById(spshid).getParents().next();
    var folderId = folder.getId();
    var contents = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId).getFiles()
    var sh;


    var oldVal;
    var newVal;

    while (contents.hasNext()) {
        sh = contents.next();
        if (sh.getName() != spsh.getName())
        {
             newVal = sh.getSheetByName('SCORE').getRange('J5').getValue(); 
             oldVal = spshg.getActiveSheet().getRange('A1').getValue();
             spsh.getRange('A1').setValue(newVal+oldVal);
         }




     }
};
```

Comment: Currently you're getting the file object not the spreadsheet. Have you tried using `getId` for the file then passing to `SpreadsheetApp.openById` ?

Answer (score 0):

After you list the files with the DriveApp, you need to get their Id and subsequently open them with Spreadsheet by Id. Subsequently, you can use the method [getSheets()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getSheets()) to obtain the sheet names. You should implement in your `if` condition to access with the SpreadsheetApp only Spreadsheets rather than all files contained in your drive folder, otherwise you will get an error.

```
   sh = contents.next();
   shID=sh.getId();
   if (sh.getMimeType()=='application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet' && sh.getName() != spsh.getName())
      {
        var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.openById(shID).getSheets();
        if(sheets.length>=1)
        for (var i=0; i<sheets.length; i++) 
         {
          //here instead of logging you can implement your desired functionality, like setValue etc.
           Logger.log(sheets[i].getName());
          }
```

Comment: Many thanks thanbks to the informations you provided I was able to make it work!

Comment: No worries, glad it helped.